# How to understand "typedef int (xxx)(int yyy);"?

Tags: c, syntax

`typedef int (xxx)(int yyy);` seems to define a function pointer named `xxx` which points to a function with a integer parameter `yyy`.

But I can't understand that syntax...Could any one give a good explanation?

---

I find `typedef int xxx(int yyy);` still works. Any difference between them?

Comment: You may find [this explanation](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) helpful.

Comment: You miss an `*`, `typedef int (*xxx)(int yyy);` defines a function pointer

Comment: @AlterMann No, it's not my code. I think it defines a function pointer, but seems not, I have no idea..

Comment: Having declared that `typedef` and `xxx a;`, under llvm I get "error: non-object type 'xxx' (aka 'int (int)') is not assignable" with any RHS I can think to try. Is `xxx` actually used by the code you've received? Otherwise maybe it's possible that the author meant it to be a function pointer, got the syntax wrong, but never used it to find out? I'm grasping at straws.

Comment: @Tommy: Try `xxx *a;`.

Comment: @icktoofay so it's not quite a function pointer, just enough to allow you to declare function pointers that have an asterisk in the declaration so as really to say "look at me, I'm a pointer"? You should write a full answer as that seems to be it.

Comment: @AlterMann While what you write really defines a function pointer, I personally like to define `typedef`s for function types itself. 1) Then it is easier to see that it is a function pointer if I use a `*` upon usage, and 2) I can prototype functions in order to require them to exactly have the right signature. If I modify them, I'll get an error instead of a mere warning.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This defines a function type, not a function pointer type.

The pattern with `typedef` is that it modifies any declaration such that instead of declaring an object, it declares an alias to the type the object would have.

This is perfectly valid:

```
typedef int (xxx)(int yyy); // Note, yyy is just an unused identifier.
 // The parens around xxx are also optional and unused.

xxx func; // Declare a function

int func( int arg ) { // Define the function
    return arg;
}
```

The C and C++ languages specifically, and mercifully, disallow use of a `typedef` name as the entire type in a function definition.

Comment: Great explanation! It would be helpful to show how this function gets called, e.g., whether it's possible to use the `typedef` name in the function call.

Comment: @verbose The function is called like any other. The existence of the typedef name doesn't affect anything. Not sure how it could be applied to a call.

Comment: you can use this function type to define a function pointer as in the example I showed to improve readability.

Comment: @JohnSmith Naked function types are a bit esoteric. It would be better to typedef a function pointer type in the first place, `typedef int (*xxx)(int)`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter I ask another question about that:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18456810/a-typedef-function-as-a-parameter-of-another-function

Comment: @Potatoswatter It is unusual to do it this way, but I don't think that the other way would be really better. There are reasons for this syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  `typedef int (xxx)(int yyy);` is the same as `typedef int xxx(int yyy);` which defines a function type. You can find an example from page 156 C 11 standard draft N1570 . Quote from that page,

`All three of the following declarations of the signal function specify exactly the same type, the first without making use of any typedef names.`

```
    typedef void fv(int), (*pfv)(int);
    void (*signal(int, void (*)(int)))(int);
    fv *signal(int, fv *);
    pfv signal(int, pfv);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have some declarator `x` in declaration `T x`, then `T x(t1 p1, t2 p2)` means **function with params p1, p2, returning the same type as the declarator x was having before**.

Parenthesis around the declarator means **apply modifiers inside the parenthesis first**.

In your case there are no modifiers inside the parenthesis. This means that there is no need in them.

Function prototype means **There is a function somewhere that has this signature and its name is Blah**.

Typedef with the prototype of the function means **Lets give a name blah to a function signature**. This does not imply that any function with this signature is existing. This name can be used as a type. For example:

```
typedef int xxx(int yyy);

xxx *func_ptr;       // Declaration of a variable that is a pointer to a function.
xxx *func2(int p1);  // Function that returns a pointer to a function.
```

Comment: `T x` would be the declaration, and `x` would be the declarator.

Comment: Right, I was thinking this but my writing was not good. I will update.