# A typedef function as a parameter of another function

Tags: c, syntax

`typedef int (xxx)(int yyy);` means define a function which named xxx with an integer parameter. you can see this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18456275/how-to-understand-typedef-int-xxxint-yyy) for details.

I have tried this in different ways, that is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef int (xxx)(int yyy);

void f1(xxx a)
{
    printf("f1:%d\n",a);
}
void f2(xxx *a)
{
    printf("f2:%d\n",a);
}
int test(int y)
{
}
int main()
{
    xxx *a;
    f1(test);
    f1(a);
    f2(test);
    f2(a);

    xxx b;
    printf("xxx's size:%d\n", sizeof(b));
}
```

output:

```
f1:4199274
f1:2
f2:4199274
f2:2
xxx's size:1
```

My question:

1. `f(xxx a)` is the same as `f(xxx *a)`?
2. `sizeof(someFunction)` is defined or not?

Comment: Regarding (2), both `sizeof(function)` and `sizeof(function-type)` are invalid is C. However, `sizeof(function-ptr-type)` is perfectly fine. I'd have to check the standard to confirm my suspicions about (1) before commenting further.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> means define a function which named xxx

It defines a function *type*.

> f(xxx a) is the same as f(xxx *a)?

Yes. But this is sort of a hack in the language. The star is just helpfully added for you because it was missing.

> sizeof(someFunction) is defined or not?

It specifically is not. You can do this with in assembly language, or by using intimate knowledge of how your program is linked, but it has no semantic meaning to C. Functions don't even need to be addressable beyond indirect jumps, as C supports Harvard architecture machines. (Also, note that two functions with the same type will usually have different sizes, as the size is determined by the number and nature of its instructions.)

C11 6.3.2.1/4 says

> A function designator is an expression that has function type. Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, … a function designator with type ‘‘function returning type’’ is converted to an expression that has type ‘‘pointer to function returning type’’.

and 6.5.3.4/1 says

> The sizeof operator shall not be applied to an expression that has function type…

It appears that your compiler is failing to apply 6.3.2.1/4. An error message is required.

Comment: +1 (and great post by you linked in the OP's question, also up-voted).

Comment: Really thanks..But I wonder, how could you know so much details about C language? And answer this question(I think it's very hard..) so quickly?

Comment: I use code::blocks IDE, it do: `mingw32-gcc.exe -c a.c -o a.o` first,then
`mingw32-g++.exe -o a.exe a.o`

Comment: @Sayakiss By using a copy of [N1570](http://undergraduate.csse.uwa.edu.au/units/CITS1002/resources/n1570.pdf), identical to the official C11 standard.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Great documentation! I will read it carefully. Really thanks!!